# Spring Boot with External JAR gets NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jar, classnotfoundexception

So I have a set of subprojects in my main project.  The first project (called `mainCode` in the example below) implements the full functionality of the application.  However, the `WidgetAImpl` and `WidgetBImpl` are separated into separate subprojects so that they can be deployed independently when they need to be fixed.  The `WidgetAImpl` and `WidgetBImpl` classes reside in the same package as the interface `WidgetInterface`.

Here's the project layout:

```
project
    + mainCode
        + /src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/Application.java
        + /src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/AppConfig.java
        + /src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/widgets/WidgetInterface.java
    + widgets
        + WidgetA
            + /src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/widgets/WidgetAImpl.java
        + WidgetB
            + /src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/widgets/WidgetBImpl.java
```

I have gradle building these in such a way that the `mainCode` project becomes our war file for deploying to tomcat and the widgets each turn out a jar file.  The goal is for the jar files to be added to tomcat's classpath and the war file is deployed separately.  I spent the day getting Gradle to build the `WidgetAImpl` project by declaring the `mainCode` project a dependency.  So Gradle builds them properly now and I have a `mainCode.war` and a `WidgetAImpl.jar` and a `WidgetBImpl.jar` file.  In the implementation, the widgets are all clumped together with an Autowired HashMap so that all implemented Widgets are created in a single HashMap at run time.  I've added the widgets to tomcat's classpath through catalina.properties sharedLoader property.

My problem is, when I deploy my war file to tomcat, I get the following error (trimmed for space):

```
2017-11-15 21:55:39.841  WARN 16687 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.mycompany.myproject.widgets.WidgetAImpl] for bean with name 'WidgetAImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/mycompany/libs/WidgetAImpl.jar!/com/mycompany/myproject/widgets/WidgetAImpl.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/myproject/widgets/WidgetInterface
2017-11-15 21:55:39.845 ERROR 16687 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3633386f: startup date [Wed Nov 15 21:55:38 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]


...


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.mycompany.myproject.widgets.WidgetAImpl] for bean with name 'WidgetAImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/mycompany/libs/WidgetAImpl.jar!/com/mycompany/myproject/widgets/WidgetAImpl.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/myproject/widgets/WidgetInterface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1364) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:639) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1456) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:220) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1243) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1089) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:663) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/myproject/widgets/WidgetInterface
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1271) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1408) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.myproject.widgets.WidgetInterface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

(Full Exception Stack Trace here: https://pastebin.com/KwaNGaeN)

It appears from this that Spring can't find my WidgetInterface.  However, I've confirmed that the WidgetInterface classfile *is* inside the war file.  Also, it's the same java package as the WidgetAImpl and WidgetBImpl (even though they're in separate files).  Why can't it see the WidgetInterface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create `common`, or `base` module, with that `WidgetInterface.java`? Add it to Tomcat as widgets. Then all other jars, and war can rely on that, common part. Tomcat will have clean path how to load it, what is used by which other module.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're saying to make a `common` module that is deployed as a jar file similar to the `WidgetAImpl.jar` and `WidgetBImpl.jar`?  Wouldn't that just pull the problem back a level to where the `mainCode` now can't find `BankInterface`?  Why can't spring see the classes in the war file when it is constructing the bean using the jar file?

Comment: Current solution means that Tomcat parts, which are loaded first, depend on `mainCode` - the interface is defined there. So you need to pull that into separate module, and use it in other modules. That way all the modules can use it, also your `mainCode`.

Comment: So I gave it a shot, and as I expected, now the `mainCode` can't find the `BankInterface`.  It seems my problem is that `mainCode` doesn't have access to the classes loaded by tomcat, or at least can't see them when autowiring.  I assume Spring is somehow being limited to only the class files within the war file?

Comment: That is strange - look here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html - it states that if you put jar file into `lib` directory it will be treated as `common` and be accessed by internals, as well as webapps.

Comment: Well I'm not putting into lib directory; I'd like to reference it from a specified location which I'm doing using catalina.properties and specifying my jar location in the sharedLoader property.

Comment: I've confirmed that when Spring is analyzing the external jar, it, for some reason, *cannot* see the libraries included in the war file.

Comment: Well, that is more, or less obvious. There are layers, and WAR is at final, dead end. It depends on other stuff located in lib, and they can rely on other... and there are some provided by app server itself.

Comment: But Spring is *also* located in the war file, so why can't it see the jars in the war file while scanning the jar file?  

Anyway, the answer was to move Spring outside of the war file as well as the `mainCode` as one subproject and `WidgetInterface` as another subproject and each widget as its own subproject all as dependencies and voila, it worked.  I'd love to know why.